# video from images, but only imagemagick created pixelized

Tags: ffmpeg, imagemagick

I am trying to make video from images. First i create images with imagemagick (simple version):

```
convert -background transparent -size 1280x720 -gravity center 
caption:'text' 0.png
```

then ffmpeg(simple version):

```
ffmpeg -framerate 0.5 -i 0.png debug.mp4
```

and this is what happens: http://prntscr.com/qy5i08 do you see the difference? Image and video resolution is the same 1280x720

I used another png image not created with imagemagick and there is no difference. Why is that?

Comment: Is you PNG color-indexed?

Comment: Why not do it all in `ffmpeg`? See drawtext filter.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was `-background transparent`
When using background black than the quality is normal.